# how to link page menu with array?

Tags: php

I'm working on orphan kid information I was see this link menu, But I don't know how to connect with my page following code:

link: `http://example.com/?m=content&a=kidinfo`

```
<?php
$m = array(             
array("title"=>"Home page", "link"=>"?m=index"),            
array("title"=>"Kids Info", "link"=>"?m=content&a=kidinfo"),                
array("title"=>"Gallery", "link"=>"?m=content&a=gal"),                              
array("title"=>"Location", "link"=>"?m=content&a=loc"),             
array("title"=>"About", "link"=>"?m=content&a=about"),              
);
?>
```

Comment: What exactly do want to achieve ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to do something along the lines of this to populate your array...

```
<?php
$baseURL = "http://example.com/";
$m = array(             
array("title"=>"Home page", "link"=>"?m=index"),            
array("title"=>"Kids Info", "link"=>"?m=content&a=kidinfo"),                
array("title"=>"Gallery", "link"=>"?m=content&a=gal"),                              
array("title"=>"Location", "link"=>"?m=content&a=loc"),             
array("title"=>"About", "link"=>"?m=content&a=about"),              
);
?>
```

Then, when you want to output your links, you can do something along the lines of...

```
<?php
foreach($m as $link) {
    $path = $baseURL . $link["link"];
    $title = $link["title"];
    echo "<a href='$path'>$title</a>";
  }
?>
```

Another way to write that foreach block is as follows...

```
<?php foreach($m as $link): ?>
<a href='<?= $baseURL . $link["link"] ?>'><?= $link["title"] ?></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The first is easier to understand for beginners, the second assumes that you have php's short tags enabled.